# How to combine standard select and select from information_schema into a single query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL/PDO query i've been using successfully and recently i manually added some 'meta' information to each column 'Comment' attribute in ALL tables in the DB.
I know i can get a columns comment using this :

```
SELECT COLUMN_COMMENT
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA  = 'Collectors'
AND TABLE_NAME      = 'list' 
AND COLUMN_NAME     = 'leader'
```

My Select that i've been using looks like this:

```
SELECT r.*, f.Fill 
FROM rateinfo r JOIN frame f ON r.FillID=f.ID JOIN list l ON l.ID=r.listID 
WHERE l.ID = 151
ORDER BY r.RateCovered DESC, r.RateReviewDate DESC;
```

How can i combine the two queries so that the comment column for each returned column is present in the associative array result set i.e.

```
$resultsArr[0]['rateConcession']
$resultsArr[0]['rateConcession']['comment'] <------- how can i get/use this syntax??
```

I have tried this subquery:

```
SELECT r.*, f.Fill, ( SELECT COLUMN_COMMENT FROM information_schema.COLUMNS )
FROM rateinfo r JOIN frame f ON r.FillID=f.ID JOIN list l ON l.ID=r.listID 
WHERE l.ID = 151
ORDER BY r.RateCovered DESC, r.RateReviewDate DESC;
```

but stuck at the 'Where criteria to use to narrow it down since this returns more than a single result  - i just want the comment per  column of the result column.
Any ideas please??

Comment: You should show us the _exact_ output you need, and ideally also some sample input data.  Off the top of my head, this is going to be hard to swing, because your information_schema query will return _rows_ containing column comments, but your second result set will have the columns as...columns.

Comment: The output i need is as stated: $resultsArr[0]['rateConcession']['comment'] - ideally -the['comment'] key is what i want to achieve. The data in the comment is just that a string which i use as a hint for users in the front end.

Comment: That's not SQL output, and it doesn't help me to give you an answer.  Maybe a PHP person could work with that...but I can't.

Comment: Updated my question tags, removed PDO and added PHP - cheers

Comment: "To make it easy", I would first get the comments of the columns, store them in a tmp array, then run the rateinfo query, loop the results and associate the column comment to the column in the loop.

Comment: Didn't quite understand your needs. You want to show only one comment per single column (you can do this through LIMIT 1) OR you want to deal with a number of comments per single column?

Comment: @ Anton - hi, yes each column has a comment so with every returned column from the select i want the corresponding comment - ideally within the returned array which is Associative (PDO) -- I initially thought of using two tables and keeping them synced but the comment attribute seems a better place since they are actually comments which hold info to help front-end users understand what the column data is - without exposing the column name in the front-end which is a security risk.